# Rendering large set of components in React

Tags: reactjs

We have an issue with our application. We are rendering a UI from JSON. Some Json contains more than 2000 elements and we are converting them to components using react. Example JSON content:

```
[
    {
        "pageNo": 1,
        "fields": [
            {
                "fieldType": "line",
                properties related to this field, max 20
            },
            {
                "fieldType": "checkbox",
                properties related to this field, max 20
            },
            {
                "fieldType": "text",
                properties related to this field, max 20
            },
            {
                "fieldType": "table",
                "rows": "200"
                properties related to this field, max 20
            }
        ]
    },
    {}, {}, {}, {},
    30 to 40 such pages
]
```

Is there any best practice that we can follow to optimize load time? Or any suggetions. Looked into react-virtualize but it loads a list in a page. We are displaying those 30-40 pages in one window. It looks like a pdf. One pdf contains n number of pages. Each page contain more than 50 components that is increasing our load time.

Thanks,
Abhilash

Comment: Implement lazy loading of the components

Comment: I agree. There is no way you'll be able to see 2000+ components at once anyways so just lazy load